# Using Data in a Tree in an addRow() function

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

So I have a flextable and I am trying to add a row. The data I want to input into the cells is located within a tree. I can't seem to find a way to bring the data over into my equation. Any help?

Here is the tree holding some sample info.

```
private Node root = buildTree();

private Node buildTree()
{
    Node root = new Node();
    root.id = "Main Component";
    root.data = new String[]{ "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example"};

    Node child1 = new Node();
    child1.id = "Part 1";
    child1.data = new String[]{ "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example"};
    root.children.add(child1);

    Node child11 = new Node();
    child11.id = "Part 1-1";
    child11.data = new String[]{ "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example", "example"};
    child1.children.add(child11);
```

I want to be able to call addRow() to add a row to my table, I'm just stuck as to how to get the information within the arrays in the nodes.

```
private void addRow(Node nde)
{
    //add first row of data, pull information from the tree
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So is the row supposed to contain the data from the full tree or just from the one node passed to addRow?

Comment: The row will just contain the data in the node passed to addRow. I just can't find a way to access that string. I figured its such a simple solution but I have yet to find an answer.

Comment: I'm calling

"addRow(root)"

and now within the addRow I am attempting to pull up the string.

Comment: So trying to access `nde.data` doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you so much, it was THAT simple. Thanks for your time!